# My buttons don't work!

Tags: asp.net, button

```
<div id="addCompany">
 <h1 class="addLink">Add a Company</h1>
 <div id="addCompanyForm">
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbxAddCompany" runat="server" 
 DataSourceID="dsNewCompanies" DataTextField="CompanyName" 
 DataValueField="CompanyID">
 </asp:CheckBoxList>
 <asp:Button ID="SubmitCompanies" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
 <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="addLink" />
 </div>
 </div>



Protected Sub SubmitCompanies_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
Handles SubmitCompanies.Click
Dim SqlConnection As New SqlConnection("Server=off- db1;uid=productsDB_admin;pwd=@password;database=Products")
For Each company As ListItem In cbxAddCompany.Items
  If company.Selected Then
   SqlConnection.Open()
   Dim sqlAddCompany As String = "INSERT INTO CompanyLink (ProductID, CompanyID) VALUES (" & ProductID.Value & ", " & company.Value & ")"
   Dim sqlCommand As New SqlCommand(sqlAddCompany, SqlConnection)
   sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   SqlConnection.Close()
   End If
   Next
   Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
End Sub
```

This is in Visual Studio 2010 VB not C#, and I can't figure out how to make the button do anything! All of the buttons on this site are set up like this and it was done by someone who is no longer with the company so I can't ask anyone for help except forums. Can anyone help me figure out why my buttons aren't firing?

Comment: if you debug, step through the code does the button click trigger your code?

Comment: What leads you to believe they are not firing? Is that just a guess or have you proven it to yourself somehow?

Comment: I have checked the database after I hit submit and nothing is happening. Nothing is even happening on the page. A Javascript box pops up with checkboxes for a user to choose from to add a new item. I check a box and click on submit and it just sits there. The new item doesn't get added or anything.

Comment: I don't know how to debug, I clicked on start debugging but the site doesn't look right at all. Is it not supposed to connect to the database in debugging mode? This site is largely database driven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the onClick property in the Button control:

```
<asp:Button ID="SubmitCompanies" runat="server" Text="Submit" onClick="SubmitCompanies_Click" />
```

Comment: I added that and the button still doesn't do anything :(

Comment: This would definitely work if my buttons weren't in a javascript fancybox. I read fancybox is a turd with ASP and doesn't allow buttons to work. Gotta find a solution to that now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code sample provided, my bet is that the problem is your event handler being on a seperate line.

While VB.NET allows you to specify your event handlers directly on the method, you must make sure the handler part is on the same line as the method signature OR that you preceed it with an underscore.

If you replace

```
Protected Sub SubmitCompanies_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
Handles SubmitCompanies.Click
```

With:

```
Protected Sub SubmitCompanies_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles SubmitCompanies.Click
```

You'll likely find it starts working.

Comment: That doesn't work....I'm not sure if it has something to do with the Javascript or what

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the fancybox plugin will not work with checkboxes and textareas. I am going to have to redo the entire site because the guy that made this site wasn't aware that it was never going to work. :(

Answer (score 0):

You are missing event on button, register onclick event for button.

if there are any validations written on button please check that first.

Otherwise i don't see any issue in click fire event.

Thanks